# How to run electricity through metal wire to (safely) act as a stylus?

Tags: capacitance, touchscreen, iphone

I’m trying to make a robotic arm draw a lowercase ‘i’ on my iPhone’s drawing app *without* lifting the stylus. The robot arm bit is another story, my current focus is trying to make a stylus out of a metal wire.

I think I can break this question down further:

1. What material is best to use? Any sources or charts I should look into?
2. How much current should be applied to this wire to safely interact with the average capacitative touch screen?
3. Does thickness of wire matter in respects to precision and current needed? Stated differently, if the iPhone X’s pixel size is about 0.05mm, what considerations do I need to make regarding the thickness of the wire?

Comment: You don't want to use metal for this. Try sponge, or conductive rubber.

Comment: Oh, wait, without lifting the stylus? What you're asking seems to rely on a misunderstanding of how capacitive touchscreens work; I don't see any practical way to do what you want (though I do see impractical ways to do it)

Comment: why do you need to pass current through the stylus?

Comment: It’s my understanding that capa touch screens work when the current is disrupted/modified. For this reason using an (E.g.) normal US quarter does not work as a touch, but the passive electrical properties of a finger does work. It was my thinking that passing a small current thought a wire would work as a touch. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to run electricity through a wire to act as a stylus. Capacitive touch screens work by sensing changes in capacitance on a screen. Just plopping a coin on a screen won't register as a touch since that coin is an open circuit and can't modify the charge on that area of the screen. The charge on the screen is still the same. Conductivity alone can't hold a charge.

Connecting a wire to the device's chassis should close that circuit and allow the wire to modify that specific screen area's charge.

1. Any material is fine, as long as it can allow charges to be attracted/repelled (form a significant capacitor plate). So, a wire connected somewhere (ground hopefully), or a big enough mass should do it.
2. 0 amps should do it. We're talking about static charge.
3. Thickness is a large factor. A wire's tip connected somewhere does modify capacitance, but not enough for the screen to register. Instead of changing wire size, consider having a conductive end effector (e.g. ball of foil). Adjust until the touches are solid and reliable.

(said end effector should hopefully not scratch the screen)